# Disable strictTemplates per file not entirely

Tags: angular, tslint, tsconfig

I have a large project with many files.

Now I want to use `strictTemplates`, so I added the following lines in:

##### tsconfig.json

```json
    ...
        "angularCompilerOptions": { 
        "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true, 
        "strictTemplates": true 
    ...
```

Now I want to disable (or overwrite) `strictTemplates` rule for certain `html-template` files. Preferably direct in the file itself.

Something like:

##### component.html

```html
// pseudo code
<!-- @ignore-strictTemplate -->
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

[ThisAngular guide page](https://angular.io/guide/template-typecheck) does not help me at all.

Comment: Did you ever get around, I have a similar problem where I have a third party directive that is causing a problem when strict is enabled. Works fine though

Answer (score 2):

According to angular [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/template-typecheck#disabling-type-checking-using-any) you can use the **$any()** type-cast function in certain contexts to opt out of type-checking for a part of the expression.